# Why Rollbar does not send Code Version info when Infrastructure is used?

Tags: logging, blazor-server-side, rollbar

I've setup Rollbar infrastructure for Blazor Server app following the docs.

```
builder.Services.AddRollbarLogger(loggerOptions =>
{
    loggerOptions.Filter =
            (loggerName, loglevel) => loglevel >= LogLevel.Warning;
});


RollbarInfrastructureConfig config = new RollbarInfrastructureConfig("my access key, "my env");
            config.RollbarInfrastructureOptions.CaptureUncaughtExceptions = true;
            RollbarPayloadAdditionOptions payloadAdditionOptions = new RollbarPayloadAdditionOptions()
            {
                    CodeVersion = "my.version"
            };
            config
                    .RollbarLoggerConfig
                    .RollbarPayloadAdditionOptions
                    .Reconfigure(payloadAdditionOptions);

            RollbarInfrastructure.Instance.Init(config);
            
            
            app.UseRollbarMiddleware();
```

I've also tried:

```
config.RollbarLoggerConfig.RollbarPayloadAdditionOptions.CodeVersion = "my version";
```

but same effect.
I get the items but none of them have the version set.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure you initialize `RollbarInfrastructure` with a proper config before adding any RollbarLogger.